# Can i use only try method in exception handling in python without use exception as e?

Tags: python, exception

Anyone can tell me about only try function is possible in exception handling in python
because i want to use only try function not exception method
Okay now i am editing the question because this is a bad practice..
Okay now i got to know about this is a bad practice so now please give this question to up and I am apologizing for this.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: You should know that this is very bad practice.  It hides all the exceptions from you, thereby making debugging much more difficult.

Comment: try to use if-else if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this is a bad practice. But here you go:

```
try:
    <your code here>
except:
   pass
```

This will try your code and if it fails then does nothing.

Example:

[image: try except with empty except]

In Python, `pass` is a null statement. The interpreter does not ignore a pass statement, but nothing happens and the statement results in no operation. The pass statement is useful when you don't write the implementation of a function but you want to implement it in the future.